# Socket.io with ack between iOS device and Node.js server not working

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, socket.io

I have a project where I have a iOS Objective-C app trying to talk to a Node.js server. I'm using [socket.io (iOS)](https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift) and [socket.io](http://socket.io) on node.js.

The problem I am trying to solve is to get a message from the device to the server, and have the server return a response. To this end I'm attempting to do it via sending a message and expecting an acknowledgement containing the data the device is after.

The device code looks like this:

```
void (^serverAck)(uint64_t, void (^)(NSArray *)) = [_socket emitWithAck:@"ListProjects" withItems:@[]];

serverAck(0, ^(NSArray* data) {
    if ([data count] == 0) {
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"CRXServer" code:1 userInfo:nil];
        failureBlock(error);
    } else {
        successBlock(data);
    }
});
```

And the node.js code looks like this:

```
var SocketIO = require('socket.io');
var io = SocketIO(8099);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('ListProjects', function(data, getProjectsCallback) {
        database.allProjects(function getAllProjectsCallback(err,  rows) {
            getProjectsCallback(rows);
        });
    });
});
```

When I attempt to run this, `getProjectsCallback` crashes the server because it is not a function. From comments made on another thread, I understand that this will be a function if the call to the server is correct and expecting an ack.

Anyone know what I've done wrong?

P.S. Her's a dump from socket.o's log showing the request coming in:

```
engine:socket packet +0ms
  socket.io-parser decoded 20["getProjects"] as {"type":2,"nsp":"/","id":0,"data":["getProjects"]} +14ms
  socket.io:socket got packet {"type":2,"nsp":"/","id":0,"data":["getProjects"]} +15ms
  socket.io:socket emitting event ["getProjects"] +0ms
  socket.io:socket attaching ack callback to event +0ms
Getting all projects ...
Releasing connection
Got the project list
/Users/derekclarkson/projects/crux-Server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:82
    throw err;
    ^

TypeError: getProjectsCallback is not a function
at getAllProjectsCallback (/Users/derekclarkson/projects/crux-Server/Server.js:20:13)
at Query.executeCodeblockCallback [as _callback] (/Users/derekclarkson/projects/crux-Server/Database.js:321:17)
```

So it looks like socket.io is attaching an ack, but somehow it's not being passed to the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's a bug or a protocol limitation, but it doesn't work when you pass an empty array to `emitWithAck:withItems:`. You'll see that server-side, `data` contains your callback function, rather than `getProjectsCallback` as you expect.

So, two options:

- in that situation, recognise that the first argument to your listener handler will be the callback, rather than the second
- or add any random data to the items array (e.g. `@[@"x"]`)

I think I would go for the second option in case someone fixes this issue in the future.

Comment: Doh. Rather obvious when I think about it. Now it's working. Thanks.